# mail does not reciveing with node mailer smtp

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-ec2, smtp, nodemailer

In my node.js application I am using nodemailer with MY SMTP configuration.
While working with local machine there is no problem. The mail does receiving while sending from AWS host.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.***.com',
port: 25,
auth: {
    user: '******',
    pass: '******
},
tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

});

I did not get any error logs.

Any help?

Comment: did you get a proper response from your smtp server? and could you specify what service you are using like mailchimp, mandrill etc.

Comment: @AJS I'm not using any service like mailchimp, mandrill etc. I'm custom SMTP configuration using my domain.. the same configuration works well in my local machine..

Comment: what  response are you receiving?

Comment: @AJS. I'm getting success response and i have also verified transporter connection that also successfull.

Comment: @prakashS - Have you checked port 25 is open in Security group ?

Comment: @PramodRaut, yes its allowed